# How to calculate percentage value for two binnary columns and one nominal column in DataFrame ine Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate-functions, melt

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

data type:

- ID - int64
- X1 - int64
- X2 - int64
- CH - int64

  | ID | X1 | X2 | CP | CH |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 111 | 1 | 0 | 10-20 | 1 |
  | 222 | 1 | 0 | 10-20 | 1 |
  | 333 | 0 | 1 | 30-40 | 0 |
  | 444 | 1 | 1 | 30-40 | 1 |
  | 555 | 0 | 1 | 30-40 | 1 |

And I need to create new column "COL1" answered on question:

- What percentage of customers had CH = '1' per combination: CP x X1 ='1' and CP x X2 = '1'

So as a result I need something like below:

| col_X | col_CP | CH_perc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 10-20 | `1.00 <- 2 IDs had X1 = '1' and CP = '10-20' and 1 of them had CH = '1', so 2/2 = 1.00` |
| X1 | 20-30 | `0 <- non of IDs had X1 = '1' and CP = '20-30'` |
| X1 | 30-40 | `1.00 <- 1 ID had X1 = '1' and CP = '30-40' and 1 of them had CH = '1', so 1/1 = 1.00` |
| X1 | 40-50 | `0 <- non of IDs had X1 = '1' and CP = '40-50'` |
| X2 | 10-20 | `0 <- non of IDs had X2 = '1' and CP = '10-20'` |
| X2 | 20-30 | `0 <- non of IDs had X2 = '1' and CP = '20-30'` |
| X2 | 30-40 | `0.66** <- 3 IDs had X1 = '1' and CP = '30-40' and 2 of them had CH = '1', so 2/3 = 0.66` |
| X2 | 40-50 | `0 <- non of IDs had X2 = '1' and CP = '40-50'` |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: Could you explain where does `20-30` and `40-50` come from?

Comment: no client has such a compartment in the cp variable, but it should be in the output :)

Comment: Do you know in advance the list of all possible CP values because I don;t see the values 20-30 and 40-50 in your sample dataframe

Comment: All possible values are: 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, but in could be possible that no client has some cp :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
cps = ['10-20', '20-30', '30-40', '40-50']

x = df.filter(like='X')
x = x.where(x == 1).mul(df['CH'], axis=0)
x = x.groupby(df['CP']).mean().reindex(cps).fillna(0)
```

##### How it works?

- Filter the `X` like columns
- mask the values other than `1`
- multiply by `CH` to ensure that only values where `CH == 1` are considered
- groupby `CP` and agg with `mean` to calculate percentage
- `reindex` to ensure all `CP`'s are present

##### Result

```
        X1        X2
CP                  
10-20  1.0  0.000000
20-30  0.0  0.000000
30-40  1.0  0.666667
40-50  0.0  0.000000
```